# how to update serialized options programatically?

Tags: options, wp-cli

I want to automate updating plugin options. There are some things that I repeat a lot.

With [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) I know I can update simple options like this:

```
php wp-cli.phar option update blog_public 1
```

However, some plugin options save their options in a serialized string.

Example of serialized option_value in wp_options:

```
a:9:{s:4:"from";s:21:"xx@xxx.com";s:8:"fromname";s:51:"xxx";s:4:"host";s:13:"smtp.xx.com";s:10:"smtpsecure";s:3:"ssl";s:4:"port";s:3:"465";s:8:"smtpauth";s:3:"yes";s:8:"username";s:21:"xx@xxx.com";s:8:"password";s:13:"xxx";s:10:"deactivate";s:0:"";}
```

How to update those options?

Answer (score 27):

WP-CLI is definitely the answer to this after the update to 1.4.0 which introduced the [pluck](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/pluck/) and [patch](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/patch/) commands for accessing serialized data in WordPress.

The pluck command takes this format for grabbing serialized values

```
wp option pluck <key> <key-name>
```

For example in the active_plugins option you can grab first item

```
wp option pluck active_plugins 0
```

The patch command takes this format for inserting, updating or removing serialized values (the action)

```
wp option patch <action> <key> <key-name> <value>
```

Deleting the first active_plugin would look like this

```
wp option patch delete active_plugins 0
```

The same pluck and patch were also added for other commands like postmeta, you can now use WP-CLI to do some cool loops for updating [WordPress serialized data programmatically](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/using-wp-cli-for-batch-updating-contact-form-7-postmeta-options/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: A few things that are not in the documentation: `wp option patch update <key> <key-name> <value>` fails if the key does not exist and updates only if it does exist. `wp option patch insert <key> <key-name> <value>` updates if the key exists and adds new if it doesn't exist.  ... this may not be intuitive if you're used to `update_post_meta` where the word update means "update or add".

Answer (score 19):

**Solved it myself, this is how to do it:**

If you want to programatically update serialized options:

download wp-cli from wp-cli.org

Find out what is the "key" for the options you are using. In this example the key is "wp_smtp_options"

If you don't know the key, search in wp_options table and try to figure it out.

Example: `select * from wp_options where option_name like '%smtp%'`

Now that you know your key, use this command to save your configuration to json file:

```
php wp-cli.phar option get wp_smtp_options --format=json > my_saved_config.txt
```

Whenever you want that configuration to be restored use this command

```
php wp-cli.phar option update wp_smtp_options --format=json < my_saved_config.txt
```

Notes:

- works in WAMPSERVER64
- works with unicode characters like ñ á é
- you can have your json file with paddings and spaces, for legibility

It would be great not having to use an intermediate file for this purpose. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Thanks - great work.  If anyone is trying to write a script without requiring external files you can just put the json in the `option update` line in single quotes.  See my implementation on line 61 here: https://gist.github.com/squarecandy/cfdead55ca1d84496044

Comment: see my answer for a "one liner"

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I do it in a bash script:

```
wp option get wp_smtp_options --format=json | php -r '
$var = json_decode( fgets(STDIN) );
$var->from = "email@email.com";
$var->fromname = "me";
print json_encode($var);
' | wp option set wp_smtp_options --format=json
```

Answer (score 0):

The [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) command [`option`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/option/) does use WordPress' [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) to do its job. Given, e.g. with the subcommand [`update`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/option/update/), a correct input, an `array`, you should be able to do this with WP-CLI. You should make use of the `--format` parameter here, to make sure you get the same, `json` works generally fine for the `update` subcommand. Note, the subcommand [`get`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/option/get/) should return you the option unserialized, because the Options API is used, which you then can save, modify and/or transfer/set-up on other/new installations.

Comment: This doesn't work: 

`wp option get wp_smtp_options > savedconfiguration.txt`

`wp option update wp_smtp_options < savedconfiguration.txt`


First command saves as array, but second doesn't accept an array. 

I guess I should serialize it first, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Did you try leveraging the `format` parameter? @lalo edit: just seen you figured it out..

Comment: in wp-cli.org doesn't say what are available options for `format` parameter. I wonder if it could be possible without having to use an intermediate file like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: You have to look at the source to get an complete overview over the `format` parameter, which differs from (sub-)command to (sub-)command sometimes. It surely is possible, for example by writing a bash script and storing the data into a variable. @lalo

Comment: here is the source code, but don't understand where are `--format` available options: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/php/commands/option.php#L200

Comment: Maybe I remember it wrong or you have to dig deeper. @lalo